# Disable Windows ComCtrls manifest in InstallShield

Tags: installshield, installshield-2012

I am building a windows installer for my .NET application and it looks like InstallShield (2012 Spring - Premier Edition) is adding [Windows Common-Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx) manifest to my icons converting them to DLLs.

This is hitting my application's performance as OS encounters a page fault as it tries to parse the icon image on launch.

Here is the manifest that IS is appending.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity
    version="1.0.0.0"
    processorArchitecture="X86"
    name="CompanyName.ProductName.YourApplication"
    type="win32"
/>
<description>InstallShield Icon Res</description>
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
            version="6.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="X86"
            publicKeyToken="<>"
            language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
        <requestedPrivileges>
            <requestedExecutionLevel
                level="asInvoker"
                uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
</trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Google "installshield disable advertised shortcut"

Comment: @HansPassant I am not sure how that will work? The reason for performance hit is icon getting converted to DLL. Even if I make it non-advertised, it will still be a DLL competing for pages with my other DLLs. Am I missing your point here or are we on different tracks?

Comment: If you disable the feature then you won't get the DLL either.  Fretting about a page hit is ... unproductive.

Comment: @HansPassant So you mean if I disable advertised shortcut, explorer will not try to parse the same on launch? I can try this. Well, actually page hit is delaying some core DLLs to load with a delay which creates a bad experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a short digression into why this is happening. The [Icon table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369210.aspx), where Icons need to be stored to support Windows Installer advertisement, requires that "Icon files that are associated with shortcuts must be in the EXE binary format and must be named such that their extension matches the extension of the target". Thus InstallShield builds the correct format file. And by "build" I really mean it stuffs the icon data in a resource on a template EXE file.

So what's the upshot? You can change the resulting manifest by editing the template. The template is stored in `...\Support\_IsIcoRes.exe`, and if you open that in Visual Studio or another resource editor, you can examine or even edit the manifest in `RT_MANIFEST (24) \ 1`. This file isn't signed (yet) because the build process will have to modify it, and thus would invalidate any signature, so your edits should be safe. That said, keep a backup of the original in case things go awry.

Comment: Thanks for the help Michael! While I appreciate the answer, is there a way to disable conversion of Icon to EXE at all? I understand MSDN documentation says that it should be EXE for shortcuts but the thing that got us tripping was that previous version of InstallShield was not adding such manifest and our icons were not wrapped in EXE.

Comment: @AkshatGoel: InstallShield has converted these to EXE for a long time, but I don't recall in exactly which version the manifest was added. It turned out that, without the manifest, the shortcut was getting a UAC shield even though its target did not elevate. There's no actual code in _IsIcoRes.exe, so perhaps the simplest thing to do would be to copy it from the version with your preferred behavior.

Comment: Yeah. That makes sense. I will test out this and also what HansPassant suggested above. Thank you :)